# When is code "legacy"?

Tags: source-code, legacy

We've all done it, we've labelled some code (often stuff we've inherited) as "legacy"? But it's still used in the production systems - so is it really legacy? And what makes it legacy? Should we shy away from this unwarranted labelling of perfectly functioning code; where the labelling is a pure convinience which allows us to push through new stuff and keep upper management nice and happy?

---

#### Summary of answers

Looking through the answers I see four general themes. Here is as I see the breakdown:

1. Any code that has been delivered: 6
2. Dead systems: 2.5
3. No unit tests: 2
4. Developers are not around: 1.5

Comment: To me, legacy means it was passed down by the ancients, having been originally written for hardware, an operating system, and an environment which is no longer supported by the original supplier.

Comment: Not sure how authoritative it is, but I found this paper informative: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode.pdf

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation

Comment: It's legacy code as soon as it's delivered and is working.

Comment: It's definitely legacy when the last person who can modify it (competently) leaves the company.

Comment: Code starts becoming legacy as soon as you step away from the chair.

Comment: it's legacy code if you didn't write it ;-)

Comment: It's legacy if the programmer no longer works there

Comment: It's legacy code if everyone that wrote it is retired or dead, and if those that continue to maintain it wish they were.  Otherwise, it's just called the existing code base.

Comment: the moment you commit the code to your repo: now people who did not wrote it have to deal with it

Comment: You have answered your own question: > **"A Legacy system is one that you inherit"**

Comment: A legacy system is any system which is currently generating a profit.

Comment: The moment you save the file, the code becomes legacy code.

Comment: While working at a client site I've actually seen some COBOL programs that were written before I was born (i.e. pre-1981). If that's not legacy then I don't know what is.

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe, given enough time, it's legacy code even if I *did* write it.

Comment: I try to think of it as: If I were to reimplement this project today, would I use the same technology ? If no, then that system is a legacy system :) .

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm rather partial to [Wikipedia's summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) myself:

> A legacy system is an old method, technology, computer system, or application program that continues to be used, typically because it still functions for the users' needs, even though newer technology or more efficient methods of performing a task are now available.

A lot of what other people are describing in their answers are *reasons* why code becomes "legacy".  But the essential question itself is this:

> But it's still used in the production systems - so is it really legacy? And what makes it legacy?

The fact that it is still used in production **is precisely what makes it legacy**.  If the code does not work properly, or is no longer used in production, then that code is "broken" or "retired", respectively.  *Legacy* means that it is still in use and works fine, but incorporates designs or techniques that are no longer in common use.

Any code or system that you either (a) would like to upgrade/update, but can't, or (b) are still in the middle of upgrading, is a legacy system.  This doesn't mean [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) or general code cleanup, it means *significant* changes to the design, possibly using a new framework or even a new platform.

There are any number of reasons why systems or code might *become* legacy:

- Lack of regular maintenance or [software rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot). Clearly if the application is not maintained regularly, it will not keep pace with major changes in the software world.  This might be due to simple neglect or it might be a deliberate choices based on business priorities or budgetary constraints.
- Lack of testing. [Another answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94007/when-is-code-legacy/94011#94011) references a popular author's hyperbolic claim of any code not covered by tests being legacy code.  This really isn't an accurate definition but it *is* a possible root cause; without good tests (automated or manual), developers become timid and afraid to make major changes because they worry about breaking something, thus leading the "software rot" above.
- Rev-locking, an often-overlooked factor which is particularly insidious in projects using large open-source libraries or frameworks (although I've seen it happen with commercial tools as well).  Often there will be major customization done to the framework/library, making an upgrade prohibitively difficult or expensive.  Thus the system becomes legacy because it runs on an older (and possibly no-longer-supported) platform.
- The source code is no longer available, meaning that the system can only ever be added to, never changed.  Since these systems have to be rewritten in order to upgrade - as opposed to incrementally/iteratively revised - many companies won't bother.

Anything that slows or stops updates to a code base can lead to that code base becoming legacy.

Now the separate, unstated-but-implied question is, *what's wrong with legacy code?*  It's often used as a pejorative term, hence the question:

> Should we shy away from this unwarranted labelling of perfectly functioning code?

And the answer is no, we shouldn't; the labeling *is* warranted and the term itself clearly implies functioning code.  The point is not *that* it's function, but *how* it's functioning.

In some cases there's nothing wrong with legacy code.  It's not a bad word.  Legacy code/systems are not Evil.  They've just collected some dust - sometimes a little, sometimes a lot.

*Legacy* becomes *obsolete* when the system can no longer serve (all of) the client's needs.  *That* label is one that we need to be careful of.  Otherwise, it's simply a cost/benefit equation; if the cost of upgrading would be lower than the cost of its benefits (including lower future maintenance costs) then upgrade, otherwise, leave it alone.  No need to spit out the word "legacy" in the same tone you normally reserve for "tax audit".  It's a perfectly OK situation to be in.

Comment: That said, tax audit should be a perfectly OK situation to be in too.

Comment: I'd say: System which can no longer be scalable with it's existing Technology Stack.

Answer (score 40):

Usually it means it's written in a language, or based on a system that you don't typically do new development in.

For example, most places don't write new programs in Cobol.  However, a large part of their business may run on apps written in Cobol.  Hence, those apps, are labelled "Legacy".

Comment: I agree with this answer most. Legacy is more about being stuck on an obsolete platform than being annoying (yet modern) code that you don't want to support. Legacy code is often quite good (otherwise no one would care if you left it behind!) but it's usually wedded to obsolescent hardware and antiquated languages/libraries/databases/etc.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy: I simply can't agree -- I've dealt with (for one example) some Java that was definitely not tied to any particular hardware, library or database -- but was as "legacy" as it gets (and was being rewritten in Java, so the language wasn't the issue either). I've also dealt with some code that *was* tied to specific hardware, but was still only *barely* edging into the "legacy" category.

Comment: @jerry: So what made it legacy? Legacy isn't a synonym for "bad".

Comment: In the case I'm thinking of, it was a fairly large distributed system (built around BEA Tuxedo). The design seemed based on text book scenarios that are intended to teach about synchronization by *maximizing* the number of times/places synchronization is needed. That (sort of) makes sense for a text book, but it's *horrible* for real designs. It was large enough that even architecting a replacement was a multi-year project. The replacement had to be done in phases with no down time, because the system was *utterly* necessary to the business.

Comment: While most of the internals needed complete replacement, operations from the user's viewpoint were considered crucial, so the re-design had to remain almost invisible to end users (except, of course, the parts that they really *wanted* changed).

Comment: Good answer.  More generally, I would say it's code you would write differently for any reason if you started it from scratch today.  That might be good code that's stuck on an obsolete platform, or modern but bad code that can't be discarded for some reason.

Comment: This is pretty much my definition. e.g. I've worked a job where new development was done in VB.NET, but there were legacy VB6 systems. Earlier, I worked a job where VB6 was the new development language, and the legacy systems were terminal-based apps written in an obscure 4GL under VMS. Legacy is whatever you used to use, but don't use for new dev work any more.

Comment: @Jerry but you do agree with Chad's answer, right? You are "*not doing new development*" directly in that java legacy code of yours. You're doing new code thus making the old one legacy, even if it's on the same language and platform, because it's **untouched code that is still running and being used (at least in the compiled form)**.

Comment: @Cawas: It appears to me that @Chad's answer would apply when/if the new system was being done in a different language, or using different hardware, etc. This was being re-developed still using Java, still using Tuxedo, etc. I don't see it as applying.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with this answer as being the correct "when" to label code "legacy". It's at a point where no new functionality/features could be added, but is critical to the business - so is supported. @Jerry, I think your Java example falls in the category of "Any code that has been delivered" tbh. it's not "legacy" because it's bad design, it's legacy because you don't want to have anything to do with it... ;)

Comment: @Jerry, I actually agree with that detail and I realized it while writing my comment. But I'd say it's a *detail* he missed. The general idea, seems to me, should obviously include your example and it doesn't require much tweaking of his statement.

Comment: Note: I rolled back the edit that was made (by someone other than the original author) as I believe it sufficiently changed what the answer said or intended.

Answer (score 29):

Legacy means any code you'd *rather* replace than work with. Given the attitude of most programmers toward most existing code, that usually includes nearly everything except what you're actively writing at the moment (and on a large project where you have to code to a frozen design, even what you're writing at the moment can be included as well).

1. The emphasis "rather" is intended to convey that legacy code also means you're stuck working with it even though you'd rather not. I'm not sure the emphasis was sufficient though. Reasons for that can vary. Some really are just too big and complex to replace. Others are interfaces to other systems. Still others are driven by politics and personalities (for example, the code is horrible, but the booth babe was amazing).
2. Another point I may not have emphasized sufficiently is that while code quality *can* be a factor, it's rarely (if ever) the sole factor -- and often not even a particularly important one.
3. I think the people pushing [unit tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) as the *sole* determining factor are like the guy looking under the streetlight for the earring his wife dropped a block away. The light may be better, but you're still looking in the wrong place. Think before you [drink the Kool-Aid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_the_Kool-Aid).
4. (A corollary to 3.) It seems to me that some people are talking more about how they wish things were than how they really are. If [John Conways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway)' [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) for an [Apple IIc Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II_series#Apple_IIc_Plus) isn't legacy, it's because it's sufficiently small and simple that it's easy to re-implement from the ground up. The most perfect unit testing ever written won't change that a single [iota](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iota#Noun).

The last point does lead to two other points I think are often true.

First, code is often retained as legacy, even when it really shouldn't be. Higher level managers generally assume re-implementing a system will cost as much or more than the initial implementation did, which is rarely true.

Second, unit tests are a two-edged sword. They make it all too easy to think that localized changes in the implementation are what really matter. To make significant improvements in a larger system, you frequently (usually?) have to change enough of the overall design that many (if not most) of the unit tests become irrelevant. Unfortunately, the presence of unit tests and the attitude they engender can make it all too easy to ignore the changes that are really necessary.

Perhaps an example of that would help: let's assume a program has a [UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) library with great unit testing, and several programs that use that library. Somebody in upper management becomes convinced that "web enabled" is important (and, just for the sake of argument, let's assume that in this case he's actually right about that). After careful review, the middle managers find that their current unit testing is sufficient that they can change from a user interface displayed via the local operating system's windowing capability to being displayed remotely via HTML/CSS/AJAX, while retaining all the original input validation.

That's great isn't it? It shows how useful unit testing can be. We've swapped out the entire implementation of the whole UI, but ensured that the look, feel, and functionality remains virtually consistent, and all user input is validated to ensure data integrity. Unit testing has saved the day!

Or not! That great, highly flexible, carefully unit tested UI library has helped blind everybody involved to the fact that for this program in its market with its users, a web-based UI is entirely the wrong thing to work on at all. What's really needed is a web service with a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) interface, and absolute *no* UI of its own at all.

Now, it's certainly true that unit testing does not, in and of itself remove people's ability to understand their market or realize that's really needed. At the same time, the old line about hammers and nails virtually leaps to mind. It can be even worse when you not only *have* a hammer, but have a *lot* of experience with this hammer, and know it's a really a high quality hammer that works incredibly well in many different situations. The very fact that it's so good at so many things in so many situations makes it even harder to recognize when it's entirely the wrong tool for the job at hand.

Comment: See, now I don't know whether to mark this up or not, sadly this is true, but I wonder if it's an attitude we need to get away from...

Comment: +1. I was about to answer something to the same extent. Legacy is any code that is used rather than actively maintained.

Comment: @Nim: I don't think it's an attitude that "we" need to get away from. It's a mere statement of the obvious. :-) Think about it for a moment and wonder what you'd consider to be legacy code if you were to arrive in a new environment; it'll be everything except the new & cool stuff that is being actively developed.

Comment: @Jerry, so you don't like unit tests then? ;)

Comment: @Nim: Not so -- I think they're useful, but *far* short of the panacea as which they're frequently portrayed.

Comment: IMHO Legacy code is a function of the programmers age, the younger programers tend to see more recent code as legacy than older programers. The tendency to discount older code is independent of how up to date the programmers skills are, an older programmer who does JavaScript programming will less likely to see C++/Fortran code as legacy than a younger programmer.

Comment: Wow, you're so way off about unit tests. Unit test protect code from future modification and prevent developers from introducing bugs. It's not about swapping anything out. Perhaps that UI library wouldn't be so great if every release introduced bugs in previously working code. Someone in upper management might have killed the project or your customers stopped using it.

Comment: @VincePanuccio: My only answer is that you really need to read what I wrote.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I have, it appears to be against testing as a practice because tests don't survive a re-architecture. To me it's not a double edged sword, it just protects what you have written so you code behaves in an expected way in the current architecture. If the overall architecture changes and unit tests break, then that's great, write new ones for the new code base/architecture. That's, of-course, my opinion :)

Answer (score 17):

Legacy code is usually orphaned in some way. The lead developer, the only guy who understood it, got hit by a bus, and his notes were written in his native Ukrainian dialect, which is now a dead language. Or, alternately, anything written in [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline).

I work on legacy code all the time. I would say the characteristics are:

- It cannot be extended without massive effort
- It cannot easily be migrated to new hardware
- It is too business critical to be easily replaced

If it doesn't have those characteristics, then it's probably not legacy. If you don't like your predecessors' [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) scripts, I sympathize, but I don't think it's legacy. I recently modernized some 15-year-old Perl script that was wedded to an obsolete [Sybase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybase#History) database. That was cake compared to making even the smallest change to our god-awful [COBOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL) accounting system.

Comment: Scary, our lead developer is Ukrainian too... haha... I agree with the middle bit of your answer, the first point - not so much - I think it depends on how your dev team is setup.

Comment: lol, you have probably managed to offend (bus drivers, the Ukrainian language, and VB6 devs) all in one paragraph. But damn did I laugh :)

Comment: I'm a time traveler from 1999, you mean Visual Basic 6 is *legacy* from 2011 onwards?

Comment: @h.j.k. I'd say pretty much anything after the advent of C#/asp.net in 2005 would be on shaky ground, but certainly once the end of support from Microsoft rolled around in 2008.

Answer (score 12):

In his book, *Working Effectively with Legacy Code*, Michael Feathers defines legacy code as code that is not covered with unit tests. That's one definition, which I agree with. I also see legacy code as old, yet still usable.

Comment: This strikes me as a case of attempting to define "anything that doesn't follow my chosen methodology" as "legacy". It's nothing more or less than a cheap debating tactic, basically just taking Godwin's law and softening the language (barely) enough to keep readers from instantly recognizing that it's nothing more than an unsupported (and often insupportable) attack any everybody who doesn't follow his preferences.

Comment: @Jerry: I agree with Feather's definition. Code without Unit-Tests is an horror to work with. If you decide you want to refactor some parts of it so it gets easier to reason about it, forget it! you may be introducing bugs and the code probably the way it is is untestable, anyway! I find Feather's definition to be unconventional, yet he is someone that made a living working with legacy code.

Comment: @devoured: unit tests are not an accurate litmus test for ability to work with code. I've dealt with code that lacked unit tests, but was a breeze -- and with code that had unit tests, and was still a nightmare. Ultimately, unit tests don't solve anything in themselves. Unit tests for a design in which (for example) the division into units was poorly done can still be utterly worthless, and the whole design (including tests) needs to be thrown out an replaced to produce anything useful.

Comment: I agree with Jerry's comments. The absence of unit tests is just one of a bunch of code smells which _might_ (or _might not_) indicate badness.

Comment: @smci, and badness *might* or *might not* be related to code having legacy status.

Comment: I too agree with Jerry's comments here, absence/presence of unit tests in-of-themselves do not really mean anything - and in some cases may lead to false confidence in changes. They are only as good as the guy that wrote them...

Comment: I again agree with Feather's definition as well as devoured. Absence of unit test is *everything* as this mean that even the most beautiful code snippet is missing it's specifications. Unit tests are 51% of the documentation and 100% of the specification of the code. A code missing most of it's it's documentation and all of it's specification should rightly be classified as legacy.

Comment: I cannot agree to the first definition. It would imply, that if I write a new codebase with a test for every unit, the code would never turn into legacy code. Such claims are ridiculous and show how severe the hype around unit tests is.

Comment: @Jerry: I don't know why you consider unit tests a "methodology". I think a definition of legacy code as code which is difficult to maintain because you don't have tests to know when you break it is a very natural and pragmatic definition, independent of any methodology.

Comment: +1 At least the definition is objective and has a real meaning, rather than just being a synonym for "bad"

Comment: @back2dos: then the problem isn't with the given definition, is with your interpretation of it. just because you (probably) associate it with old code, it doesn't really need to mean that.

Comment: The problem with a reasonably sized code-base without automated regression tests (unit tests), is that when you start to modify it, you can easily introduce reggressive bugs. That means it's hard to move the code forward and so it tends towards "legacy". Still, I agree that Feathers "definition" appears to be a dogmatic and propaganda-like promotion of unit testing. Hence I marked up the comment by @JerryCoffin

Comment: Related: *[Does it make sense to write tests for legacy code when there is no time for a complete refactoring?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/227893)*.

Answer (score 8):

Technically, legacy is any code that is ready written. So as soon as it is in production, it's legacy. Because there is already value there, you can't just throw it out... You have to deal with it.

**It's "before your time" but "still your headache"**.

Answer (score 5):

Legacy code is code that's only remains in the code base because a lot of things would stop working otherwise. In other words: it's only reason for being is backward compatibility.

You'd rather change it or even throw it away, but you can't because you will break all code relying on it (which might be code that you cannot adapt accordingly). Therefore you have to keep it (and sometimes even maintain it), but you wish all new code not to be written against it.

An example are deprecated methods of a library's API. They're still there, so that if whoever updates the library can still build his project, but they are marked as deprecated and you compiler should give you a warning.

Another example are all those weird tricks Microsoft does to make programs run that were written for versions of their OS they have completely deprecated. The pinnacle of this being:

> I first heard about this from one of the developers of the hit game
>   SimCity, who told me that there was a critical bug in his application:
>   it used memory right after freeing it, a major no-no that happened to
>   work OK on DOS but would not work under Windows where memory that is
>   freed is likely to be snatched up by another running application right
>   away. The testers on the Windows team were going through various
>   popular applications, testing them to make sure they worked OK, but
>   SimCity kept crashing. They reported this to the Windows developers,
>   who disassembled SimCity, stepped through it in a debugger, found the
>   bug, and added special code that checked if SimCity was running, and
>   if it did, ran the memory allocator in a special mode in which you
>   could still use memory after freeing it.
>   [-- Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/APIWar.html)

Answer (score 4):

Legacy entails inheritance. Legacy code is simply code that you inherit from the past. It's legacy code even if you wrote it yourself before!

All other considerations descend basically from the fact that you did not write it specifically for your current project. It's not necessarily a bad thing per se.

Comment: The past could be 1 day, 1 hour or 1 year. That doesn't make it legacy.

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that what is considered legacy code is dependent on multiple things, and the tag 'legacy' is probably organisation-specific.

If the hardware/OS it runs on are old and have been discontinued by the vendor - strike 1.

If it's more work to try to fix it, than to rewrite it, for any reason because

- the original developer/s are gone
- the program is badly written
- it can be done better on a newer platform, and is still worth it to the company

to do so

- original source is no longer available and/or missing pieces

Strike 2.

A merging of multiple organisations into one - Strike 3 - one side is probably going to get tagged as legacy.

Is there a better, cheaper alternative sold as a third-party application and/or service - strike 4.

Is the organisation something like a hospital or a school district where consistency is valued over new tech when it comes to daily operations? It'll take longer for an application  to be considered legacy compared to the same application in a commercial/competitive organisation.

If the company is a small development company that keeps enhancing/supporting the application to do what the customers need, is it considered legacy code, or just 'old' code.
I know a company named Mc2Ok - they developed the software on what seems to have been Windows 3.1, and have just kept carrying it forward. It still very much has a Windows 3.1 look and feel, but they added a web interface to it as well. It is a two-man developer company (my guess), and I'd say when they quit working on it, then it'll be considered legacy, and time to migrate a year or two after if using it. But that could be another 10 or more years.

Sometimes when management changes, it can change in waves that have many trickle effects... Depending on the clout of the new management, it can render many applications legacy that might otherwise be just fine.

Each organisation, I believe, has to define what 'legacy code' means to them.
I used to look through *[The Sunday Times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sunday_Times)* classifieds every week to see what organisations were looking for. That used to be my barometer for what was no longer relevant (that is, legacy). Well, *The Sunday Times* is no longer relevant :-)
And we can generalize that COBOL is legacy, [ASP Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) is legacy, etc...
But I believe each organisation has to decide when an application is considered legacy for it.

Comment: +1, nice answer - better to consider something legacy from the perspective of the org...

Answer (score 0):

Code is legacy when one is afraid to change it, because he may break it. It is even more painful when the whole system may be knealed by changes to that code.

This is why I also agree with Michael Feathers' definition. Code that has good unit tests can be changed fearlessly.

I also think that legacy code has nothing to do with how old it is. One can write legacy code from the start.